# How to upload site to specific subpage

Tags: web-hosting, web-development, ftp, uploading

I have two sites. One I created in Adobe Muse and uploaded it to randomdomain.com through FileZilla. The other was created outside of Adobe Muse, and has its own CSS stylesheets and PHP code.

I want to upload this second site to randomdomain.com/**subpage.html**

Things I've tried:

- Uploading the second site to a new folder ("Subpage").
- Moving "subpage.html" to the root folder, while keeping other assets in the Subpage folder.
- Renaming "subpage.html" inside the subpage folder to index.html.
- And so on.

So far I haven't been able to access the second page at the address I wanted it to be. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: More details are required. For example, *haven't been able to access the second page*, How? What error do you get? What web server? Have you set ownership and permissions? And so on. Cheers!!

Comment: How: I can't access the page at domain.com/subpage.html through my browser. When copying the direct FTP URL from FileZilla I can actually access the file in Chrome.
What error: either a white page, or an error page from my hosting company.
What web server: I honestly wouldn't know, and can't find out from my hosting company's website. I'm guessing "regular" is not the right answer here ;)?
Ownership and permissions: haven't changed anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're making a subfolder, you should let all the files in the folder, rename the subpage.html to index.html and access as: randomdomain.com/subpage/

If you want a subpage (randomdomain.com/subpage.html) then drop ALL the files on the main folder OR drop in a subfolder (randomdomain.com/stuffforthesubpage/) and correct all the links on your subpage.html to link correctly (change your "css/css.css" to "stuffforthesubpage/css/css.css")

Comment: I think you're suggestion should have worked, but--unfortunately--it didn't. I've ended yo creating a new sub domain and creating a redirect at domain.com/subpage. Thanks for your input though!

Comment: Then you should take a look on your .htaccess on the main domain and the apache.conf because something fishy is going on there.